# call member function in another class c++

Tags: c++

I have a class called Ball and a class Player.Inside my Ball class I create two pointers of type Player and I have two member methods so when I change the ball I can point to different players(current and previous). So I know that if I want to call the member methods of Ball inside a method in class Player they have to be static (and I also think that static methods operate with static variables too) but I seem to have huge difficulty and whatever I try I get a different error.

Here follows **Player.h**

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
#include <iostream>
#include "Player.h"

using namespace std;

class Player
{
    public:
        //constructor of players
        Player(const string &,int,int,int,int); //name,num,x,y,target_line

        //setters and getters
        //player's movements and functions
        void pass(Player*);

    private:
        string Name;
        int Num;
        int X;//0-5
        int Y;//0-9
        int Movement_line;
        int Target_line;

};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

Here follows **Player.cpp** in which in method pass the problem I described occurs.

```
#include "Player.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Team.h"
#include "Ball.h"
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


Player::Player(const string &name,int num,int x,int y,int target_line)
:   Name(name),
    Num(num),
    X(x),
    Y(y),
    Movement_line(y),
    Target_line(target_line)
{
}

//setters and getters and other member functions

void Player::pass(Player* next){
    changeCurrentToPrevious();
    changeNextToCurrent(next);
}
```

Here follows **Ball.h**

```
#ifndef BALL_H
#define BALL_H
#include "Player.h"

class Ball
{
    public:
        Ball();
        Player* current;
        Player* previous;

        /*void setX_ball(int);
        int getX_ball() const;
        void setY_ball(int);
        int getY_ball() const;
        void assign();*/
        static void changeCurrentToPrevious();
        static void changeNextToCurrent(Player*);


    private:
        int X_ball;
        int Y_ball;
};

#endif // BALL_H
```

Here follows **Ball.cpp**

```
#include "Ball.h"
#include "Team.h"
#include "Player.h"

Ball::Ball()
:   X_ball(2),
    Y_ball(5)
{
    current = NULL;
    previous = NULL;

}

static void Ball::changeCurrentToPrevious(){//when pass occurs
    previous = current ;
}

static void Ball::changeNextToCurrent(Player* next){
    current = next;
}
```

Comment: The exact same question was asked one hour ago. What happened to that one?

Comment: To call a static method in another class, you have to put the class name before it: `Ball::changeCurrentToPrevious();`.

Comment: **So I know that if I want to call the member methods of Ball inside a method in class Player they have to be static.** Why do you think that? You can call regular methods if you have a variable of type `Ball` or `Ball*` in the `Player` class.

Comment: Guys thanks for the answers. Please note that I just got my hands to C++ it is my first project and I may say wrong things. Thanks for the replies I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a static method of another class, you need:

```
void Player::pass(Player* next){
    Ball::changeCurrentToPrevious();
    Ball::changeNextToCurrent(next);
}
```

Either that, or you'll store a pointer/reference in Player to ball, then you can call via that.

Comment: Thanks that really helped. An extra question does the same thing applies to variables that are static from class to class?

Comment: I followed your suggestion by now I seem to have another problem. I declared as statics  Player* current and Player* previous but now in constructor of Ball (Ball.cpp) it says undefined reference to current and previous

Comment: Look, you only want something static when you're _sure_ you'll only need exactly one of that, regardless of the number of objects you have. I'm not convinced this being the case here. Perhaps you want a pointer/reference (and no statics).

Comment: yeah yeah I realised it now. It's just I am new with c++ thus I am not so versatile

Answer (score 1):

Of course if you make a `public` method `static`, then you can call it with ClassX::methodY() from anywhere, but then object-orientation goes out the window, and you are actually writing code in `C`, not in `C++`.

And of course no, a static method cannot magically have access to member variables of an instance.

So, the methods ***must not be static***; they must be non-static ("instance") methods.

Which means that in order to invoke them, you must have a reference to a `Ball`.  Which in turn means that it is not enough for a `Ball` to have references to `Players`; each `Player` must also have a reference to the `Ball`.

Comment: I think this is what will solve the problem. I have to change the way I approach the problem. I appreciate your answer.